# Folder structure of InstallShield suite project

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, suite

I have a problem concerning folder structure of a built InstallShield suite project.

I have several MSI packages included into the suite, and I want them to be copied from source media and not extracted from setup.exe (that's an option when clicking on the MSI package, general tab -> location).

That means I'd have small setup.exe and every MSI in it's own folder. But by default, the folder name resembles GUID i.e. {xxxxxxxxx}.

I didn't find any option in the suite project to change the folder name. The only "solution" was to open the project file (it has XML structure) and change the folder tag there. Is there any better way of changing folder names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet; this is a gap in the InstallShield IDE.

In an ideal world, would you rather this folder follow the display name you've selected for your package (which requires display names to be distinct), or to be a separate field?

Comment: thanks for quick response, it's just that it would be good to have an option to change default folder names of the packages

Answer (score 0):

In 2012 Spring, I was able to rename the Package Files folder for each included package and the corresponding folders used it.

Comment: If you provide a bit more information, the answer may be useful, otherwise it's of no use.